# Improvements for the new add comment feature in the Android app

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, comments, android-app

The new commenting feature (0.1.28) is pretty awesome. I've a couple issues though:

1. It only works on answers, not on questions.
2. When you tap the "add comment" button, the keyboard and the textfield that pops up can cover the whole area you were just reading. This is specifically annoying for the add comment button on the last answer in a list.

   My suggestion: push the bottom of the screen up to above where the keyboard shows up. Basically, scroll the visible portion of the screen to the bottom of the answers list. (There might be a better way though.)
3. There's no way to remove the comment bar if I change my mind and decide not to comment. Perhaps an `x` or a swipe down?

Comment: Definitely agreed on #1 and #3, but could you clarify #2 a bit? Do you mean the app should keep the y-value of the viewport the same when the keyboard and textbox appear, so there's no vertical scrolling? What if you were looking at something on the bottom-half of the page, wouldn't it still disappear?

Comment: Right now, the keyboard slides over whatever was on the bottom half of the screen. I'm suggesting that the bottom of the comment block should be scrolled so that it's visible just over the top of the keyboard.

Comment: @Kasra 1 seems implemented in .31. I wonder, are you planning on using it for editing comments too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of version 0.1.33 coming out later today:

1. [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
2. When you hit "Add comment" the viewport will now scroll to the top of the answer you are responding to, same as if you hit on the blue part of "Replying to []'s answer:" above the edit box.
3. [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

Per your question in the comments, it'd be a good idea to also use the new interface for editing comments too, but that doesn't happen yet. Perhaps make a [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) for that, if you don't I will make one for myself and reap the reputation :)