# Use the Android app's new commenting interface for editing comments too

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, comments, android-app, comment-edits

Recently, the Android app introduced a new way to submit comments while still being able to view the answers etc. (i.e., not in a new activity).

It'd be great to be able to edit comments with this interface, too.

Refer: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/196914/168660

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Done as of version 0.1.34, coming out later today!

Comment: Great! Small request: The confirmation dialog that comes up when you try to cancel editing a comment shouldn't have "Erase" as one of the options. Could be confusing. Also, maybe this is a good time to bring [this up again](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/196291/dont-offer-the-edit-option-for-comments-after-the-5-minute-window-in-the-andr)

Comment: Yeah I'm not a huge fan of the phrasing there, I just didn't want the positive confirmation button to say "Cancel".. I'll gladly consider any suggestions you or others may have for the text :) Relevant UX post: http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/35753/what-to-call-cancel-when-cancel-is-already-the-default-action/35777

Comment: How about something like: "Are you sure you want to stop editing this comment and discard the draft?" or "Are you sure you want to discard your edit?" Yes (I'm Sure)/No (Continue editing). Or Discard/Go back. Just ideas.

Comment: I like it :) Look for the change in 0.1.36.